# Is it possible to not include publisherID in the filename for applicationStorageDirectory for adobe air app?

Tags: air, filenames

I see that in the applicationStorageDirectory, the filename consists of userName, the application ID, and the publisher ID. Is it possible to not include the publisherID? I ask because when I digitally sign the app, and look at the applicationStorageDirectory filename, the username and application id is fine and meaningfull but the publisherID is a bunch of cryptic looking values, and I would rather have the filename to be just userName and application Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the API enables this right now